# How can i use lighting like clara.io with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

Currently I'm showing an object downloaded from calra.io,but I'can make it like what's showing in clara.io.

I've tried all kinds of lights in three.js,such as `spotLight`,and with `HemisphereLight`,and can't get the effect.

my

[image]

clara.io

[image]

Well,mime is kind of funny.It seems lose the color of object itself.

Maybe I should use image-based-lighting,how can i do that?

Anyone has solution?

Comment: Well,actually the json file has wrong data,the material's ambient is wrong color.Not clear for the reason why clara.io loaded wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those darker parts maybe use another material.

Comment: I just download the `json` file in clara.io,it should be right

Comment: In the .json file should be the materials defined. Like i understand three.js , it should not depend on the used light.

Comment: You're right,i've found the loaded `json` is a type of `scene`,it contains all the light info,but why it doesn't work.What i need to do?

Comment: I've found this link https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/libs/SceneLoader.js,I will have a try

Comment: I would try to search the .json file for the set material properties. Maybe i am wrong, but i couldn't explain that behavior in another way.

Comment: Well,`objectLoader` is now the `sceneLoader`,it should have parsed all the info such as material.